# DataTable Server-side processing ajax error

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, datatable, datatables

I have a form/page in which do a search. That action returns datatabel type (this is a requirement) then the results I have to show in jquery datatable and the processing has to be done server-side.

I read the documentation and got some examples but I can't get it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $("#searchResultTable").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "Report/CustomServerSideAction",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns":[
        {"data": "ID"},
        {"data": "Name"},
        {"data": "Active"},
        {"data": "OrderBy"},
        {"data": "StoredProcedure"},    
        {"data": "SSRSFileName"},
        {"data": "SSESStoredProcedure"}
    ]

    //buttons: [
    //    "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"
    //]
  });
 });


@using System.Data
@model System.Data.DataTable
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="card-box table-responsive">
        <table id="searchResultTable"  class="testClass table table-striped table-colored table-teal">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow item in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            switch (col.DataType.ToString())
                            {
                                case "System.Decimal":
                                    <td class="pull-right">@Convert.ToDecimal(item[col].ToString())</td>
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    <td>@item[col].ToString()</td>
                                    break;

                            }

                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomServerSideAction()
{
     var table = Models.SearchResult.Results;

     return Json(new { draw = 100, totalRecors = 30, dislayRecord = 10, data = table }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

 public static class SearchResult
{
    public static DataTable Results { get; set; }
}
```

This gives an error

> DataTables warning: table id=searchResultTable - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on your question?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here - I think you are confusing [C# Datatables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) and [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/). You seem to be trying to populate the table in the View by passing a C# Datatable object, and using a foreach loop, and also trying to populate it using the jQuery Datatables ajax API. so you are mixing server-side and client-side table population. I think your first step is to decide which method you want to use to populate the table.

Comment: @markpsmith hope I don't. So I have stored which return DataTabe, that is a result of the search (requirements is to get the result in DataTable). Then data has to be shown in jQuery datatable. also, the requirement is to use server-side processing. I hope that you understood me

Sorry for my English

Comment: So you want to populate a table by passing the data to the View, and then apply the jQuery datatables functionality?  Does the table populate ok without the jquery datatables code?

Comment: Yes exactly, I send data to the view then I would like to apply jQuery datatable functionality. as you can see upper in my code I already apply datatable but I don't know how to implement server-side processing. (if i did on right way). here is [image](https://ibb.co/cMmrGb) of the table, is with datatable but without serverSide and data is properly  loaded

Comment: My understanding of 'implement server-side processing' is using the jquery datatables API to populate the table via Ajax and you would NOT pass the data to the View.  I think that is what you want, but I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: ok let say that is what i want. You are right i geting data twice. I going to try without passing data to the view. Thanks

Comment: so even as you said i cant get the result. i have everything the same just i dont pass danta to the view now so i get data from ajax and same issue.